# Increase search size string ctrl-G Grid in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a dummy question:P

I am working on Microsft Dynamics AX 12 and I have a requirment that says I have to increase the search text in some grids. 
The worflow  is quite simple. Just open any AX Form that contains a GRID , then press the ctrl G shortcut. After that will appear some searchboxes ,these searchboxes have maximum length of 256 chars.

My problem is that I would like to increase the input text length of these textboxes and I do not how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the length of the individual fields in the grid by setting the `DisplayLength` property on the extended data type or the field control itself.

The display length of the search field should be identical to the field length.

If there a build-in restriction on the length of the query range value, there is nothing you can do about it, other than raise a support case with Microsoft. See [here how to do so](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/axsupport/2016/04/28/cloud-powered-support-logging-support-incident-for-ax-2012-4/).

Comment: Hmm, Looks like the display length of the search field and the field length are not identical. I changed the display length of the field to 1000 and then I made a database synch. After that I checked the searchtextbox and still the max length was 256 chars.

Comment: Display length is for display! Can you give a screen shot?